# collect2: fatal error: /usr/local/bin/gnm returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I wrote a linked list as

```
In [69]: !cat linked_list.cpp                                                                                                                         
//linked list: inserting a node at beginning
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
void insert(int x);
void print();
struct Node *head; //global variable, can be accessed anywhere
int main() {
    head = NULL; //empty list
    printf("How many numbers?\n");
    int n,i, x;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the number \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        insert(x);
        print();
    }
}

void insert(int x) {
    Node *temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    (*temp).data = x;
    (*temp).next = NULL;
    head = temp;//insert to the head
    if (head != NULL) (*temp).next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void print() {
   struct Node *temp = head;
   printf("List is: ");
   while(temp != NULL)
   {
       printf(" %d", (*temp).data);
       temp = (*temp).next;
    }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Tried to run but get error report:

```
gcc linked_list.cpp                                                                                                                         
collect2: fatal error: /usr/local/bin/gnm returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
```

gcc provide few helpful hints.

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: `Temp` is already a pointer.  You don't need to put an asterisk in front of it to dereference it.  You do, however, have to use an arrow to dereference, not a dot, as in `temp->data`

Comment: Looks like C to me, not C++. Why does the file have cpp extension?

Comment: This is a problem with the compiler, not with your code. Is it this problem? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/32516

Comment: Ah, my mistake. `(*temp).next` should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a pointer to a structure, as in the case of `temp` in your `insert()`, instead of doing stuff like

```
(*temp).data
```

you can use the arrow operator and do

```
temp->data
```

---

Since this is a C program, when declaring structure variables of the structure `Node`, you must use

```
struct Node var_name;
```

instead of

```
Node var_name;
```

And in C, it's better not to explicitly cast the return value of `malloc()`.
See [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

So change the declaration of `temp` in `insert()` to

```
struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

in place of `Node *temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`.

---

And if you are trying to add new elements to the start of the linked list, you could change the `insert()` function to something like

```
void insert(int x) {
    struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
      temp->next = head;
    }
    head = temp;
}
```

---

With these changes, I got the following output:

```
How many numbers?
4
Enter the number 
12
List is:  12
Enter the number 
34
List is:  34 12
Enter the number 
56
List is:  56 34 12
Enter the number 
778
List is:  778 56 34 12
```